# Explanation for condition for newton's method

Tags: derivatives, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson

[Newton's metho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)d solves for $f(x)=0$ by iterating over possible solutions. the rate of convergence of this scheme is quadratic if 3 conditions are satisfied:

[image]

Why does $f''$ have to be continuous?

Also how does condition 3 translate to condition b?

Comment: These are not *necessary* conditions. They are *sufficient* conditions. You can have functions $f$ and starting points $x_0$ that do not meet these conditions, yet convergence is still quadratic. However, if you have any function that does meet these conditions, then convergence is guaranteed to be quadratic.

Comment: Thx, I changed the title.